# Gulp concat adding files in JS folder twice to all.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

## Update #1: Clarified question

---

## Problem

- `all.js` works when piped into the dist folder, uglified and then renamed to `all.min.js`
- However, I'm trying to get `all.js` into assets/dev/js without Gulp concat adding the two files `countup.js` and `scripts.js` twice and then a minified version `all.min.js` into assets/dist

### gulpfile.js

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require("gulp");
var postcss = require("gulp-postcss");

// All of your plugins
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");
var cache = require("gulp-cache");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var csswring = require("csswring");
var imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
// var jshint = require("gulp-jshint");
// var lost = require("lost");
var minifyHTML = require("gulp-minify-html");
// var moment = require("moment");
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
// var rucksack = require("rucksack-css");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var size = require("gulp-filesize");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
// var upload = require("gulp-awspublish");

// Sync browser, whip up server
gulp.task("browser-sync", function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: "./"
    }
  });
});

// Reload page automagically
gulp.task("bs-reload", function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

// Compile Sass into CSS, apply postprocessors
gulp.task("styles", function(){
  var processors = [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version"]}),
      csswring
  ];

  gulp.src(["assets/dev/css/**/*.scss"])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/dev/css/"))
    .pipe(rename("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/dist"))

    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

// Show any JavaScript errors
gulp.task("scripts", function(){
  return gulp.src("assets/dev/js/**/*.js")
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit("end");
    }}))
    .pipe(concat("all.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist'))
    .pipe(rename("all.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/dist"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

// Minify images
gulp.task("images", function(){
  gulp.src("assets/dev/img/**/*")
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/dev/img"));
});

// Minify HTML
gulp.task("html", function() {
  var opts = {
    conditionals: true,
    spare:true
  };

  return gulp.src("*.html")
    .pipe(minifyHTML(opts))
    .pipe(rename("index.min.html"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/dist"));
});

// Size of each of the files
gulp.task("size", function(){
  gulp.src(["*.html", "assets/dev/css/**/*.css", "assets/dev/js/**/*.js", "assets/dev/img/**/*", "assets/dist/**/*"])
    .pipe(size())
});

// Deploy
// gulp.task('publish', function() {
//   var publisher = awspublish.create({
//     params: {
//       Bucket: 'bdnsunproduction'
//     }
//   });

//   var headers = {
//     'Cache-Control': 'max-age=1209600, public'
//   };

//   return gulp.src(["*.html", "assets/dist/css/**/*.css", "assets/dist/js/**/*.js", "assets/dist/img/**/*"])
//     .pipe(awspublish.gzip({ ext: '.gz' }))
//     .pipe(publisher.publish(headers))
//     .pipe(publisher.cache())
//     .pipe(awspublish.reporter());
// });

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
  gulp.watch("assets/dev/css/**/*.scss", ['styles']);
  gulp.watch("assets/dev/js/**/*.js", ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch("*.html", ['bs-reload']);
  gulp.start("images", "styles", "scripts")
});
```

### Folder structure

[image]

Comment: Where are you concatenating to all.js? It looks to me like you are concatenating to a file called scripts.js.

Comment: @crowmagnumb My bad on that, yes, it's all.js. Just fixed that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with plumber, are you certain it's not caused by that being in your pipeline?

Comment: An example of the project structure may help provide an answer. The gulp tasks alone look correct. Are you seeing only `all.js` in `assets/dist/js`?

Comment: @ArrayKnight I've clarified my question a bit. I've also posted a picture of my file structure. So basically, I'm looking to get all.js into `assets/dev/js` and all.min.js into `assets/dist`. However, when I use Gulp the all.js file concatenates everything in my assets/dev/js folder twice.

Comment: @crowmagnumb Could be a pipe issue. I've clarified my question and added a picture of my folder structure.

Comment: Is all.min.js also filled with duplicated content?

Comment: All.min.js is currently not being filled with duplicated content as both the expanded and the compressed files are going to `assets/dist`. However, when I try to put `all.js` into `assets/dev/js` that's where I run into problems with Gulp concat doubling up JS files.

Comment: You are trying to put the output back into the source directory? That would undoubtedly form a feedback loop resulting in the output you are seeing. Wouldn't it?